# The "sailplane" tag description needs to be revised

Tags: discussion, tags

The [sailplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailplane) tag description needs to be revised-- it works fine as a general description of a sailplane, but it is confusing as an ASE tag, since we also have the tag "glider".  The tag description should clarify that the concept of a "sailplane" is a subset of the concept of a "glider".

Current tag description--

> A glider or sailplane is a type of glider aircraft used in the sport of gliding.It has rigid wings and an undercarriage. Some gliders, known as motor gliders, are also used for gliding and soaring, but have engines which can be used for extending a flight and, for some types, for take-off.

New tag should description should read something like (and this isn't intended to be the exact final wording)  --

> A sailplane is a kind of glider, with conventional aerodynamic control surfaces, intended to be able to soar.

**Actually I'm still learning how to edit tags-- I went ahead and made the edit and it is in the review queue.  If it does not pass, I will modify this question to so indicate that the change is still needed.**

**The edit was approved, but I am still suggesting a slight modification-- now done**

Comment: why close the question? you can accept the answer for example

Comment: ok, will do that

Comment: *A glider or sailplane is a type of glider aircraft*? How does this work at all as a description, general or otherwise, for sailplanes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Done](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/15908/revisions) with minor adjustments to reflect the usage and an alternative, it now reads:

> Use with [glider] for sailplanes: a type of glider intended for soaring and designed with conventional aerodynamic control surfaces, else use [glider] only.

Comment: Consider adding "only" at end, to avoid any implication that [glider] should not also be used on questions bearing the tag [sailplane]

Comment: @quietflyer: slight modification for you: **Use with [glider] for sailplanes ...** -- all good?

Comment: yes, thanks, looks good.

Comment: @quietflyer: PS that's the excerpt (usage guidance) done, the wiki itself is pending another approve besides mine: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/57522

Comment: OK, didn't really even realize that tags had two different descriptions, the "excerpt" (which appears to be usage guidance), and the "wiki"-- still learning about how all this stuff functions--

Comment: @quietflyer: convoluted UX if you ask me :)

Comment: What is UX-- I don't know that shorthand

Comment: @quietflyer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience / PS wiki is now approved